# path problem when using 'require' and symbolic links

Tags: ruby, path, symlink, require

I've got the following scripts:

- "/folderA/bin/command.rb", which calls `require 'some_library'`
- "/folderA/lib/some_library.rb"
- "~/scripts/command.rb", which is a symbolic link to "/folderA/bin/command.rb"

When I run `ruby ~/scripts/command.rb` (calling the symbolic link) it works fine, but because of the symbolic link, `__FILE__` is "~/scripts" and not "/folderA/bin/". My best idea to solve this path problem is the following:

```
$:.push File.dirname(Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath) + '/../lib'
```

This solution looks really dirty. Is there a better way to organize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to create a self-containing gem of what is in /folderA and then use the code you need in ~/scripts from the gem (i.e. require 'folderA')

hope this help to find a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is so helpful advice for all kind of 'path problem' .